# How to put id inside the newUser using Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

i have a signUp form, i am giving email and password from frontend, and active, role_id field from the typescript.. I am getting active in the consoled output but not the role_id. i guess if i can get role_id inside consoled output of ts file then my error may solve. i am getting all the required fields in the apiservice section but not in my component file.. Can anyone help me to solve this.

Comment: is this the complete code of the `ts` file?

Comment: ya it is so much of signup form

Comment: what are the two console outputs you have given?

Comment: i updated in question

Comment: I thnk you need to assign role_id from form instead if adding it manually?? You have role_id in form?

Comment: i had updated form in question

Comment: add, `user.role_id = this._id`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164691/discussion-between-sravan-and-bhrungarajni).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take a `loggedIn variable` and should use it to `toggle` the alert popup,

**Conponent Variable:**

```
public loggedIn = false;
```

**Login method:**

```
login(email, password) { 
    this.localSt.store('boundValue', email); 
    var data = { 
    email: email, 
    password: password 
    }; 
    this.ApiService 
    .login(data) 
    .subscribe( 
            user => { 
            this.signIn.hide(); 
            this.loggedIn = true; 
            this.toasterService.pop('success', 'SignIn Successfull'); 
            this.myFav = true; 
        }, error => { 
            this.myFav = false; 
            if (error.data && error.data.length > 0) { 
            this.toasterService.pop('error', error.data); 
            } else { 
            this.toasterService.pop('error', 'Something went wrong!'); 
            } 
    }) 
}
```

**Popup method:**

```
openPopup(event) { 
    if (!this.loggedIn) { 
        event.preventDefault(); 
        this.signIn.show(); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is not correct due to `public` is a keyword used in classes.

change:

```
public user:NewUsers = new NewUsers();
public _id:any=2;

newUser(user) {
  var data = {
    email:user.email,
    password:user.password,
    active:user.active,
    role_id:this._id
  }
  //....
```

to:

```
let user:NewUsers = new NewUsers();
let _id:any=2;

newUser(user) {
  var data = {
    email:user.email,
    password:user.password,
    active:user.active,
    role_id:_id
  }
  //....
```

and it should work. You also could wrap a class around your remaining `ts` code and afterwards you can set those fields `public` in that class.

Comment: that data is taking properly, i need the user output

Comment: i don't get what you say

Comment: i pasted consoled outputs again in question